# Go HTML templates for multiple sites

Tags: go, go-html-template

I'm preparing an application that will serve several different sites that have a common admin panel (a page with different themes to simplify).

Each of these "themes" will have different needs. For example while all of them show a list of services, some of them will show an associated image too. For the ones who don't I would prefer to avoid the DB calls to fetch them (different logic to render the pages).

In Laravel (a PHP framework) this would be a perfect use for view composers.

What would be the design of such a system in go?

I was thinking in some kind of "hooks" that each theme can register to run functions to fetch and add data for a specific template. There's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a list of service objects to the template, you could easily decide inside the template what you want to show. If you decide to show a service's image, you could call the `ServiceObject.ImageURL()` (which would then lead to a database call). If you're not calling this function, there will be no database query issued.

A sample using the [pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2) template engine:

```
{% for service in services %}
    {% if page.theme == "simple" %}
        <p>We don't show any image in the simple theme.</p>
    {% else %}
        {# This would lead to a database call and return the image path #}
        <img src="{{ service.ImageURL() }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another idea would be to simply create an individual template per theme (extending the common base template); you don't have check for the theme inside the template then.

Comment: The first idea is one I didn't think of, not only pass to the templates plain maps but fully featured objects it's a good idea. Defeating the eager loading with repeated calls it's another issue, but the idea can be applied in other places. The second one I'm already doing that: one independent set of templates for each theme in the site

Comment: You could cache the image URL (or any other database result) directly in the object (or use any other cache layer to accomplish that).